# Return row of Data Frame based on value in a column - R

Tags: r

My R data.frame `df` looks like:

```
     Name     Amount
1    "A"      150
2    "B"      120
3    "C"      "NA"
4    "D"      160
.
.
.
```

I want to get the Name and Amount row when I do something like `min(df$Amount)`.

That gets me the minimum number in the Amount column, but how do I get the Name in that same row? Or the entire row for that matter?

Name should be "B" in this case.

Similar to `Select * Where Amount = min(Amount)`

What is the best way to do this in R?

Comment: Subsetting is quite important to learn if you really want to use R efficiently, so perhaps you want to take a look at [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) to get started.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

@Zelazny7's answer works, but if you want to keep ties you could do:

```
df[which(df$Amount == min(df$Amount)), ]
```

For example with the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                 Amount = c(150, 120, 175, 160, 120))

df[which.min(df$Amount), ]
#   Name Amount
# 2    B    120

df[which(df$Amount == min(df$Amount)), ]
#   Name Amount
# 2    B    120
# 5    E    120
```

**Edit:** If there are NAs in the `Amount` column you can do:

```
df[which(df$Amount == min(df$Amount, na.rm = TRUE)), ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `which.min`:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('A','B','C','D'), Amount=c(150,120,175,160))
df[which.min(df$Amount),]

> df[which.min(df$Amount),]
  Name Amount
2    B    120
```

From the help docs:

> Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or maximum
>   of a numeric (or logical) vector.

Comment: What if I have NA data in my column? Can I use na.rm=TRUE in which.min argument?  Doesn't appear to work.

Comment: you don't have to use `na.rm` at all. Add some NAs to the data.frame I constructed and see for yourself. You can check the functionality with this `which.min(c(rep(NA, 10), c(1:5)))`

Comment: yeah but if I take Max, then it returns the NA value.  So how would I do this if I want the max instead of the min?

Comment: um, no, it doesn't! Can you post some code of what you're experiencing?

Comment: it does if I just do max(df$Amount).  You're right, not when using which.max, but get a NAs induced by coercion warning.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the syntax provided

```
 Select * Where Amount = min(Amount)
```

You could do using:

```
 library(sqldf)
```

Using @Kara Woo's example `df`

```
  sqldf("select * from df where Amount in (select min(Amount) from df)")
  #Name Amount
 #1    B    120
 #2    E    120
```

Comment: That's a simple cheat for developers used to standard programming protocols, but how is performance?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by("Amount") %>% slice(which.min(x))
```