# Compare rows of data frame to "master" row/s

Tags: r

Today while working out an answer to someone's question I realized I have been leaning on for loops for a while, which tends to be a sin considering R is known for how well it can it can use vectorized functions.

Say we have a data frame in which we hold our "conditions", these are row/s of data which we want to use to compare to our Data. If one of our "master" rows fully matches a row of the data frame, we want to print "match".

```
# Data to be checked
DF<-data.frame(A=c(1,4,5,6),B=c(1,5,4,2),C=c(5,6,3,2),D=c(1,2,3,4),
               E=c(4,2,3,4))

# Our condition/master data
Compare<-data.frame(A=4,B=5,C=6,D=2,E=2)
```

By using a for-loop this is an easy task but is taxing once we create larger and larger data sets:

```
#This Works, but ew
for(i in 1:length(DF)){
    ifelse(DF[i,]==Compare, print("match"),print("no match"))
}
[1] "no match"
[1] "match"
[1] "no match"
[1] "no match"
```

My question is how would someone do this **without using a for-loop in base R**. I realize packages such as `compare` and `sqldf` can do this with ease, but I am wondering if anyone can do this in base R. *I'm thinking this is obvious but I can't quite figure it out.*

EDIT:
As @Frank asnwered in the comments 
`rowSums(DF == Compare[rep(1, nrow(DF)), ]) == ncol(DF)` works great if all the data is numeric. Lets complicate things and say that in our master list there is string data to be matched as well

```
# Sample Data
DF<-data.frame(
A=c("N","J","K","L"),
B=c(1,3,4,2),
C=c(5,4,3,2),
D=c(1,5,3,4),
E=c(4,2,3,4),stringsAsFactors=F)

Compare<-data.frame(A="J",B=3,C=4,D=5,E=2)

#This Works
for(i in 1:length(DF)){
    ifelse(DF[i,]==Compare, print("match"),print("no match"))
}
```

***Research:***

I see that we could use 'merge' to compare, but this would not allow me to know where my matches were in the original data, I will only see the returned matches:

[Fetch all the rows in a data frame matching with rows of other data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759419/fetch-all-the-rows-in-a-data-frame-matching-with-rows-of-other-data-frame)

Something below sort of does it, but impossible to scale.

```
which(DF$A == Compare$A & DF$B==Compare$B & DF$C == Compare$C) #etc.
[1] 2
```

[Return row of Data Frame based on value in a column - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831580/return-row-of-data-frame-based-on-value-in-a-column-r)

Comment: `rowSums(DF == Compare[rep(1, nrow(DF)), ]) == ncol(DF)`? If you have multi-row master/compare examples in mind, maybe edit to illustrate.

Comment: @Frank That does work if the rows are all numeric data (which they are), I did not think to simply compare the sums. Lets say that some of the rows contained strings to be matched mixed in the with numerical data. I will edit my question.

Comment: The fact that R knows how to handle data in vectorized way doesn't take away from loops. They have their place in any R code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `merge`:

```
Compare$in_compare = "match"
merge(DF, Compare, all.x = TRUE)
#   A B C D E in_compare
# 1 1 1 5 1 4       <NA>
# 2 4 5 6 2 2      match
# 3 5 4 3 3 3       <NA>
# 4 6 2 2 4 4       <NA>
```

If you prefer not modifying `Compare`, then we can use `transform` for in-place modification in a one-liner:

```
merge(DF, transform(Compare, in_compare = "match"), all.x = TRUE)
```

#### Timing

```
set.seed(47)
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")
diam = unique(diamonds)
DF = diam[rep(1:nrow(diam), times = 10), ]
# 538k rows, 10 columns

compare_rows = sample(nrow(diam), size = 10000)
compare_df = diam[compare_rows, ]

# test:
merge_result = merge(DF, transform(compare_df, result = "match"), all.x = TRUE)
apply_paste_result = transform(DF, result = apply(DF, 1, paste, collapse = " ") %in% apply(compare_df, 1, paste, collapse=" "))
do_call_paste_result = transform(DF, result = do.call("paste", DF) %in% do.call("paste", compare_df))

sum(merge_result$result == "match", na.rm = TRUE) #10000
sum(apply_paste_result$result) # 0!!!
sum(do_call_paste_result$result) #10000
```

Did a bit of digging, seems like the `apply_paste` method doesn't work well with decimals. I didn't dig deep enough to understand why or to try to debug, but it's clearly not working here. The same code works fine on the toy example. Looking carefully, `do.call("paste", head(DF))` surprising produces a different result than `apply(head(DF), 1, paste, collapse = " ")`, in the 4th row the `apply` method has a `"4.2"` where the `do.call` method has a `"4.20"`... perhaps this is related. My guess is something happens when `apply` coerces the data frame to a matrix, but as I said this seems surprising.

So, omitting that method from the benchmark, it looks like the `do.call` paste method is fastest! Personally, I think I'd still probably go with `merge` as it seems like the right tool for the job... the strange bug in `apply_paste` method illustrates a risk of clever hacks.

If performance is *really* a concern, then `data.table`  will be substantially faster than either of these methods:

```
library(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(DF)
compare_dt = as.data.table(compare_df)
dt_result = merge(DT, compare_dt[, result := "match"], all.x = TRUE)
sum(dt_result$result == "match", na.rm = TRUE) #10000


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  merge = merge(DF, transform(Compare, in_compare = "match"), all.x = TRUE),
  do_call_paste = transform(DF, result = do.call("paste", DF) %in% do.call("paste", compare_df)),
  dt_result = merge(DT, compare_dt[, result := "match"], all.x = TRUE)
  times = 20
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
#          merge 5905.6842 6171.2211 6473.5351 6253.0117 6946.098 7246.2727    10
#  do_call_paste 4269.8849 4635.2662 4850.4076 4824.5035 5196.911 5289.6226    10
#      dt_result  460.4646  494.7083  555.8484  538.2203  614.905  683.1518    10
```

Comment: I figured there would be a creative way to do this with merge. This works with character data as well.

Comment: Not a very fast solution, though: 'gregor 1829.139 1896.0745 1971.4576 1946.2760 2028.607 2552.494   100   c'

Comment: @iod at this scale the benchmark is meaningless. Simulate `DF` with 500k rows and `Compare` with 10k rows and see how things play out.

Comment: @iod updated with reasonable benchmarks. It's very close. `merge` is a **tiny** bit faster overall.

Comment: @Gregor could you include the `do.call` answer into these benchmarks?

Comment: @Wimpel sure! You win the base R race!

Answer (score 3):

This will work in baseR

```
DF[ do.call("paste", DF) %in% do.call("paste", Compare), ]

#   A B C D E
# 2 4 5 6 2 2
```

or just:

```
do.call("paste", DF) %in% do.call("paste", Compare)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `merge` again as you can specify `all.x` (i.e., `LEFT JOIN`) to keep original data. Below uses `within` and `transform` as context managers to add/updated *result* column and return an updated data frame:

```
final_df <- within(merge(DF, transform(Compare, result = "match"), all.x=TRUE),
                   result <- ifelse(is.na(result), "no match", "match"))    

final_df
#   A B C D E   result
# 1 1 1 5 1 4 no match
# 2 4 5 6 2 2    match
# 3 5 4 3 3 3 no match
# 4 6 2 2 4 4 no match
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(DF,1,paste,collapse=" ") %in% apply(Compare,1,paste,collapse=" ")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Which is sort of cheating because apply is itself a loop, but this is still way faster than your solution:

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min       lq       mean    median         uq       max neval cld
  iod  375.289   488.41   627.6017   570.742   705.7295  2050.474   100  a 
   op 9070.273 10491.32 14143.7312 11770.471 15281.4865 96645.749   100   b
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well too (both numerical and character), @Gregor 's output was just a closer to the expected.

Comment: Because it said "match"/"no match"? Or because it was added to the DF itself? Because either is extremely simple with my solution (or Wimpel, which is frankly better and less convoluted).

Comment: keep in mind that paste0(1,0,0) gives the same result as paste0(10,0) ! Should probably be fine, but perhaps better be safe and use a separator (in this specific usecase)....

Comment: @iod Because it modified the existing df, which just saves a step in the long run.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't get this method to work with non-integer numeric data. See the comment on my answer for a little more detail. I didn't dig enough to figure out why, but it's very unexpected...